# How to post "multiple select" value into datatables in codeigniter

Tags: php, json, ajax, codeigniter, datatable

i have 'multiple select' value in my table, when i try to post it in my datatable it says 'No matching records found'. i'm using 'json_encode' to post the array to database.

my table look like this.

my tb_produc:

```
+------------+--------------+---------------+------------+
| id_product | name_product | id_categories |  price     |
+--------------------------------------------------------+
| 1          | cola         |   ["1","3"]   |  1         |
| 2          | burger       |   ["2","3"]   |  4         |
+--------------------------------------------------------+
```

my tb_categories:

```
+------------+--------------+
| id_cat     | name_cat     |
+---------------------------+
| 1          | drink        |
| 2          | food         |
| 3          | fat          |
+---------------------------+
```

when i try to show it on datatable after join table, it says 'No matching records found'.

model:

```
function get_all_product() {
$this->datatables->select('id_product, name_product, name_cat, price');
$this->datatables->from('tb_product');
$this->datatables->join('tb_stock', 'id_categories=id_cat');

$data = $this->datatables->generate();
```

controller:

```
function get_product_json() { 
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo $this->m_table->get_all_product();
}
```

view:

```
<tr>
    <th>Id</th>
    <th>Product Name</th>
    <th>Categories</th>
    <th>Price</th>
</tr>
```

js:

```
var table = $("#fproduk").dataTable({
'aoColumnDefs': [{
    'bSortable': false,
    'aTargets': -1
 }],
initComplete: function() {
    var api = this.api();
    $('#fproduk_filter input')
        .off('.DT')
        .on('input.DT', function() {
            api.search(this.value).draw();
    });
},
    oLanguage: {
    sProcessing: "loading..."
},
    processing: true,
    serverSide: true,
    ajax: {"url": "../datatable/get_produk_json", "type": "POST"},
          columns: [
              {"data": "id_product"},
              {"data": "name_product"},
              {"data": "name_cat"},
              {"data": "price", render: $.fn.dataTable.render.number(',', '.', '')}
        ],
        order: [[1, 'asc']],
rowCallback: function(row, data, iDisplayIndex) {
    var info = this.fnPagingInfo();
    var page = info.iPage;
    var length = info.iLength;
    $('td:eq(0)', row).html();
} 

});
```

Other Datatable that not use 'multiple select' work fine but not with it.

What i want on my datatable result is like this.

```
+------------+--------------+-------------------+------------+
| Id         | Product Name |  Categories       |  Price     |
+------------------------------------------------------------+
| 1          | cola         |   Drink, Fat      |  1         |
| 2          | burger       |   Food, Fat       |  4         |
+------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Thank you for your attention.

Comment: For database normalization purposes, do not store comma separated values in the database.

Comment: so, how do i store multiple selected data ?

Comment: store them in third table name product_category, which save only product_id,category_id, you can easily save multiple categories for same product.